# Probability of intersection of permutations without repetition

Tags: probability

The question states:
True or false test has 10 question and we know that 5 of them are supposed to be true and 5 false. What is the probability that if we randomly assign true/false (knowing that we need to use 5x true and 5x false) the first two OR the last two questions are marked true.

My solution:

$P = (A \cup B)$

$P = P(A) + P(B) - (A \cap B)$

and I computed  $P(A) = 5/10 * 4/9 = 2/9$
and assume that $P(B)$ is the same. However how do I get $P = (A \cap B)$

Comment: First, your notation can be improved.  You write $P=(A\cup B)$ and then later write $P=P(A)+P(B)-(A\cap B)$.  You seem to be using $P$ both as the probability measure function, and also as a value... but later omit the probability measure function.

Comment: Second, you calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)$ just like you do for finding $\Pr(A)$.  The first question was true with probability $\frac{5}{10}$.  The second was true given that the first was true with probability $\frac{4}{9}$.  *We can now skip ahead to the last questions!*  The ninth question was true given the first and second were true (*ignoring questions 3 through 8*) with probability $\frac{3}{8}$ and so on... We then apply the multiplication principle and conclude.

Comment: For what it's worth, Combinatorics is the easier approach: $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}} ~: ~D = \binom{10}{5}.$$  Then, $$N = \left[2 \times \binom{8}{3}\right] - \binom{6}{1}.$$ You can use the above computation as a *sanity-check*, to make sure that the approach that involves the probability of various *events* yields the same answer.